# Show that 2Z and 3Z are not isomorphic - question on proof

Tags: ring-theory

I need to show that $2\Bbb Z$ and $3\Bbb Z$ are not isomorphic.

I found a contradiction as follows: let $p$ be this isomorphism from $2\Bbb Z$ to $3\Bbb Z$.

Then $p(4) = p(2*2) = p(2+2)$, so
$p(2)p(2) = p(2)+p(2)$.
Since $p(2)$ is in $3\Bbb Z$, let us call it $3k$ where $k$ is an integer.

So
$9k^2 = 6k$
$⇒k = 2/3$

This is a contradiction because $k$ is an integer.

My confusion here is that this does not rely on the bijectivity of $p$! Where does this fail for a homomorphism?

Comment: Is it linked to my implicit assumption that k=\= 0?

Comment: What are $2Z$ and $3Z$, rings without multiplicative identity, i.e., ideals of the ring of integers? If not, how is $4$ in $2Z$? If so, $2Z$ and $3Z$ are in bijection.

Comment: @pjs36 sir can you elaborate your comment. I didnt get it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$9 k^2 = 6 k$ (for integer $k$) if and only if $k = 0$.  Now here's the point where you use bijectivity: if $k = 0$, $p(2) = 0$ so $p$ would not be one-to-one.

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you very much.