# Show that the rings $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Here I am under the impression that $2\mathbb Z$ and $3\mathbb Z$ are the sets of even numbers and multiples of $3$ respectively and the operations are usual addition and multiplication. This is an exercise in Fraleigh *Abstract Algebra*.  I believe that $2\mathbb Z$ and $3\mathbb Z$ are isomorphic as groups on addition.  I started a proof by supposing that there was a ring isomorphism, $f$,  in hopes of finding a contradiction with $f(x\cdot y) = f(x)\cdot f(y)$.

Comment: @AlexR Not everybody drops the "i" from "ring" if the $1$ is dropped.

Comment: @AlexR Some authors do not require that rings have a multiplicative identity (and will use the term *unital ring* to indicate rings that do).

Comment: [Same problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1277844/29335) but perhaps a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** A ring isomorphism is in particular an isomorphism of the underlying abelian group under addition, but the abelian groups $n \Bbb Z$, $n > 0$, each have only two automorphisms; using this one can show that there are only two isomorphisms (of abelian groups) $n \Bbb Z \to m \Bbb Z$ for any $n, m > 0$.

Comment: So, are you saying that since 2Z and 3Z both have exactly two generators, {2, -2} and {3, -3} then any group isomorphism f:2Z -> 3Z must be such that f(2) = 3 or f(2) = -3.  and f is completely determined by this choice. So  there are only 2 such functions, namely f(n) = 3*n/2 and f(n) = -3*n/2.  Neither of which preserve the operation of multiplication (which can be easily checked).  Therefor,  there can be no ring isomorphism.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Yes, that's exactly it. I must say, though, the economy of Hagen's solution is quite nice.

Answer (score 9):

In $2\mathbb Z$, there exists a generator $a$ of the additive group such that $a+a=x^2$ has a solution. This is not the case for $3\mathbb Z$.